# how to run codeiginter project downloaded from github

Tags: php, git, codeigniter, github, xampp

i have downloaded zip folder from github , link of github code is here

https://github.com/jekkos/opensourcepos

i have extracted this folder in xampp htdocs folder as POS folder and made database with the name of github_pos in mysql. but when i try to run through local host i get this error. 
enter image description here
[image]
can someone help me how to run project downloaded from github ?

Comment: https://github.com/jekkos/opensourcepos  .. Here Is Steps are mentioned are u checked

Comment: ye i followed these steps but there is nothing special in these steps. plz help me. can you run this code on your machine to check the error

Comment: @ohk wait.. i try and tell u the issue :)

Comment: thanks in anticipation

Comment: Did You Give Permission for Folder named `pos` in htdocs?

Comment: permission ? how ?

Answer (score 1):

You are going right way. There is no serious issue with your installation. Your installation step should be:

**Step 1:** Clone/Download zip from git.

**Step 2:** Import database to phpMyAdmin (SQL file located in the root/application/config.php)

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => !empty(getenv('MYSQL_HOST_NAME')) ? getenv('MYSQL_HOST_NAME') : 'localhost',
    'username' => !empty(getenv('MYSQL_USERNAME')) ? getenv('MYSQL_USERNAME') : 'root',
    'password' => !empty(getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD')) ? getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD') : '',
    'database' => !empty(getenv('MYSQL_DB_NAME')) ? getenv('MYSQL_DB_NAME') : 'open',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => 'ospos_',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

**Step:3** Import database.sql file (located in database folder).

```
       - Go to localhost/phpmyadmin
       - select your empty(or your database)
       - select "Import" menu option from the top.
       - Click brows button and select your database.sql file.
       - press "go" button bottom of the screen
```

now, within few moment your database will be update(add new tables require in the application.)

**Step:4** access your project with **localhost/pos/public** instead of **localhost/pos**

Your facing access forbidden issue because you don't have access permission by default you can find configuration in the Apache .htaccess config file. Hope this will help you..!

Greetings!

Comment: CAN YOU EXPLAIN STEP 2 A LITTLE MORE ?

Comment: I GOT THIS error when i tried to access localhost:/pos/ public, 
This page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @HinaKhan Your url should be http://localhost/pos/public/ not localhost:/pos/public. check updated answer.